# System.OutofMemoryExeption в библиотеке ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet

Tags: c#, excel

Это старый проект, писался на данной библиотеке.
У меня 2 проблемы.

1. Каждый раз при сохранении значений добавляется новый лист.
2. Может при переполнении вылезти System.OutofMemoryExeption;

Мой код:

```
  Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
  Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("Первый Лист");
   while(true)
   {
       //Парсинг и запись ввсего....
       worksheet.Cells[NA, 129] = new Cell("1");
       worksheet.Cells[NA, 130] = new Cell("1");
            // Сохранение значений
            workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);
   }
string file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + @"\Desktop\Парсинг\Спарсенные_Данные1.xlsx";
            // Сохраняю в файл все
            workbook.Save(file);
            workbook.Worksheets.Clear();
```

Comment: А зачем при каждом сохранении значения добавлять лист? Оправдан ли бесконечный цикл без условия выхода?

Comment: @gil9red Ну там выходит при определенном условии. 'workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);' Ну по идее я туда сохраняю спрасенные значения, а потом через него сохраняю, и я не понимаю почему добавляются листы